# how to make makefile for java with external jar file

Tags: java, makefile

I need to make a makefile that compiles and executes my classes with an external jar file..
I have 4 classes;`sync.java, FileSynchroniser.java, DirectoryTracer.java and SyncFileTracer.java`. 
I also need to include `gson-1.7.1.jar` ..
Heres my make file

```
.SUFFIXES: .class .java

JAVAC= $(JAVAHOME)\bin\javac
PATH=$(JAVAHOME)\bin;$(PATH)
CLASSPATH=.;$(JAVAHOME)\lib\classes.zip;$(JSDKHOME)\lib\classes.zip
DEST=.
DOC=.
JAVA=$(JAVAHOME)\bin\java
JAVACFLAGS=-deprecation

.SUFFIXES: .java .class

.java.class: 
   $(JAVAC) -classpath $(CLASSPATH) $(JAVACFLAGS) $<

CLASSFILES  = sync.class \
          FileSynchroniser.class \
          DirectoryTracer.class \
          SyncFileTracer.class

SOURCEFILES = sync.java \
          FileSynchroniser.java \
          DirectoryTracer.java \
          SyncFileTracer.java

# begin ---- JAR support ----------     
JARFILE= gson-1.7.1.jar     

$(JARFILE): $(CLASSFILES) $(SOURCEFILES) 
jar cfm0 $(JARFILE) <<manifest.tmp  $(CLASSFILES)>>

# end ---- JAR support ----------       

all : $(JARFILE) $(CLASSFILES) doc

doc : $(CLASSFILES) 
    javadoc -version -author -d $(DOC) $(SOURCEFILES) 

install : 
    copy $CLASSESFILE $(DEST)

clean: 
    del $(CLASSFILES)
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you know about **ant** or **maven**?

Comment: yes but I should make a makefile.. its one of the requirement haha

Comment: Care to explain what's wrong with your current makefile?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you referring to making the makefile in a Linux OS?

Check this - make makefile guide

> http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/howto_makefiles.html

or this - example

> http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/javamakefiles.html

hope it help.